# Android CalendarView display only the current week

Tags: android, calendarview

I want the CalendarView which will display only 1 week.

For example: from this Monday to this Sunday (Current week) and if I swipe the next Monday to the next Sunday. Is that possible?

I tried this so far but it doesn't work:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_week_view, container, false);
    calendarView = (CalendarView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendarViewWeek);
    long date = calendarView.getDate()+7;
    calendarView.setMaxDate(date);
```

Comment: Check below links of library which is helpful to achieve your functionality. https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View & https://github.com/Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView

Comment: ok thanks! So there is no "normal" way to do it?